# Its not working for youtube, vimeo and google map Iframe url change for page builder

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

Its not working for youtube, vimeo and  google map Iframe url change but image url change working good.

I need to apply same process for youtube, vimeo and  google map src url change how can it possible ??

Hare is the image change live url: http://jsfiddle.net/eDMmy/688/

And I am triad to change same optional youtube, vimeo and  google map Iframe url

```js
//Set up the dialog box
$("#myDialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  title: "A Dialog Box",
  buttons: {
    'OK': function() {
      var video_to_update = $(this).data('link');
      var textValue = $('#myTextBox').val();
      video_to_update.attr('src', textValue);
    },
    'Close': function() {
      //alert('The Close button was clicked');
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EA6TIfSXpeI" allowfullscreen="" width="350" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EA6TIfSXpeI" allowfullscreen="" width="350" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe>


<div id="myDialog">
  change url<br/>
  <input type="text" id="myTextBox" />
</div>
<script>
  $("iframe").click(function() {
    var x = $(this);
    $("#myDialog")
      .data('link', x)
      .dialog('open');
    var url = x.attr('src');
    $('#myTextBox').val(url);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: unclear what your issue is.... You tried to replace it with an iframe and you can not do it?

Comment: you want same functionality for vimeo, youtube and google maps ??

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Hi "epascarello", Update this code to I am  tried to replace

Comment: vimeo doesn't allow to embed it directly... you have to follow this documentation for it https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed, check this link https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-oembed-examples/blob/master/oembed/js-example.html

Comment: This is vimeo embed  and I need to change src url same as http://jsfiddle.net/eDMmy/688/     ( vimeo embed <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/21253329" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> )

Comment: Anybody can help me